# Redeeming, sort of. Need a better word!

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-requests

My site has a feature where users can buy, or they can obtain a code that will allow someone else to buy it for them.

The part of the page that lets the buyer input the code and gift the item to the user who gave them the code is labelled like this:

> ___ a Gift Code.

What can I put in the blank? Or is there a better label I can use?

Comment: Well, to me, "redeem" has the meaning that the person doing the redeeming will receive the item, but here it is the other way around.

Comment: So is this like a gift registry where a buyer can purchase one of the registered items for the owner of the registered list?  IF so, then you could call it "*Purchase a Gift*". It may not be necessary to go into the details of how that gift is identified (i.e., via the gift code) in the label.

Comment: @Jim I see, that makes sense.

Comment: I might have come up with a suitable answer if you asked on uxSE where there's scope to improve on the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ***trade in***  *a Gift Code* ? or simply ***use*** *a Gift Code*? Even ***exchange*** *a Gift Code* can be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You could say ***utilize*** a Gift Code or ***provide*** a Gift Code.